# Click one random element out of many

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm working on a `DOM` with a portion that has many `elements` I want to `click` on. Eleven `elements` to be precise, but all I need to do is to `click` on just one out of the eleven `elements`.

I wrote codes to do this, but the clicking is not random.
Here's what i did:

```
element1.click() || element2.click() || element3.click() || element4.click() || element5.click() || element6.click() || element7.click() || element8.click() || element9.click() || element10.click() || element11.click();
```

Comment: Well neither of those techniques will select something at random, only Math.random would be of any use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your elements to an array, then use Math.random() to select an index.

```
const elementList = [element1, element2, ..., element11];
elementList[Math.floor(Math.random() * elementList.length].click();
```

Comment: @IvakaZakuri Great! If an answer helped you, you should upvote it and select it as the answer.

Comment: ,how do i pick it as the answer?

Comment: @IvakaZakuri There should be a check-mark under the up/down vote section that allows you to "accept" the answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Find all the elements you want to click on (here i'm selecting all checkboxes but you could select all `a` tags or anything with a given classname for example)
2. Pick one at random.
3. Trigger a click on it.

EG:

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");//select the elements
var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * elems.length);//get a random index from 0 to element length
elems[rnd].click();//click it
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" name="a">1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="b">2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="c">3</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="d">4</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="e">5</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="f">6</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="g">7</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="h">8</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="i">9</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="j">10</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="k">11</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store all the elements in an array and then randomly select one element to click:

```
const elements = [element1, element2, element3]; // ...and so on
const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * elements.length);
const randomElement = elements[randomIndex];

randomElement.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an array with all elements in it.
Than, you can pick randomly one element of the array and run the click()-method.

```
var allElements = [
  element1,
  element2,
  ...
];

var randomElement = allElements[Math.floor(Math.random() * allElements.length)];

randomElement.click();
```